# WFI seems not work as expected in ARMv7 plus RTOS

Tags: arm, interrupt, rtos

I am working on ARMv7 cortex-a7 (dual-core) with an RTOS, now I am trying to use WFI instruction in IDLE task.

I asked the vendor of the cortex-a7 if WFI/WFE can work or not, and got the answer is 'yes'.
So I put the WFI in the RTOS IDLE task as follows,

```
.type cpu_intrpt_save, #function
cpu_intrpt_save:
    MRS     R0, CPSR
    CPSID   I
    DSB
    BX      LR

void idle_task(void *arg)
{
    uint8_t cpu_num;


    /* avoid warning */
    (void)arg;
    cpu_num = cpu_cur_get();

    while (TRUE) {
....
....
        cpsr = cpu_intrpt_save();
        next_tick = get_first_timer_timeout();
        adjust_tick_timer(next_tick);
        __asm__ volatile ("wfi":::"memory", "cc");
        cpu_intrpt_restore(cpsr);
        /// adjust_tick_timer(normal_tick_rate);
    }
}
```

In above code, I firstly get the tick when the next first timer event occurs, and use it to set the tick timer (descrease the number of ticks, something like tickless kernel). Then I called 'WFI' instruction to put CPU into standby mode, waiting for interrupt to arrive.

But the codes seemed not work, the WFI did NOT put CPU into waiting for interrupt mode, so the loop runs all the time adjusting the tick timer continuously (so the tick timer cannot interrupt the loop).

I tried with removing OS_INTRPT_DISABLE/ENABLE around WFI, but got the same result.

###### Edit with testing in baremetal mode with JTAG debugger

I tried following codes by downloading/debugging them with JTAG.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int count = 5;
    int result = 0;

    __asm__ volatile ("wfi":::"memory", "cc");
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        result = result + i;    // <<< Set breakpoint here
    }

done:
    // We should rather use 'WFI' here.
    goto done;
}
```

I set a break point after WFI instruction with GDB, and free run the code. The break point did NOT hit, until I type ^c to interrupt the free running.

With this testing, I think the WFI instruction works as expected!

I don't know what wrong with the code, or did I missed some critical part?

Comment: you sure you cleared the interrupt, etc..?   did you create a minimimal complete example (not part of the rtos but dedicated test?)

Comment: I updated the question with `cpu_intrpt_save` function, which disabled interrupt and returned CPSR to restore later.  I was trying to write a minimal test of WFI, but to do that in a baremetal mode is NOT easy, at least I have to setup vectors and startup code. It is also difficult to check if the minimal test is working (I am using JTAG debugger, but it seems WFI is NOT working as it is defined when a debugger is attached). If you have a such test, I am really appreciate if you can share it.

Comment: it is easy compared to the debug you are facing.  it is easy compared to rtos work at this level. actually its one assembly file with less than a dozen lines, right?  to see if wfi works with the debugger connected or not.

Comment: In fact, I use the JTAG debugger to debug above code, and I single stepped WFI, I found the CPU move to the next instruction instead of stopping at WFI waiting for interrupt. That is why I suspected that tick timer's timeout is changed continuously in the while loop.....

Comment: Updated the question with baremetal testing of WFI in ARMv7 SOC, it worked as expected. So the question now is why it failed in idle task, did I miss something, or had something wrong in idle task?

Comment: possible you have an interrupt not cleared/always asserted, but you should see that interrupt handler being buried.  I dont remember without looking, but can wfi be disabled in the core.  single stepping may defeat wfi, what if you use a breakpoint on some instructions (add several nops and trigger last one) or are you saying that single stepping in a specific test it does not step through the wfi?

Comment: using a debugger in general affects the normal state of the processor.  If you are trying to single step through this code then it is likely the interrupts are firing during your steps and the wfi is not expected to wait since at human single step speed there is a pending interrupt waiting to be serviced.

Comment: I tried disable interrupt before calling WFI and enable interrupt after it, got the same result. I suspected that debugger may impact the WFI's behavior, so I put a breakpoint after WFI, but it is hit immediately when I 'continue' running the code. And I also ran the codes freely without attaching JTAG debugger, and got the same result. I did NOT know WFI could be disabled, I tested it in a baremetal mode listed in the question, and put a breakpoint after WFI, let the code run, the breakpoint is NOT hit, until I input ^c in GDB.